# How to get Java to give Alloy more memory

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, alloy

I am using `alloy4.2`, and I am not able to tell it to use more memory.
I am not a Java expert and I suspect the problem is in how I'm configuring Java.
I am using `OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_131`.
I have also tried `1.8.0_151`. 
My VM is running in **Ubuntu x64**.
Under the Alloy Options tab, **Maximum Memory To Use** is always stuck at the default of **768M**.
I am using a VM that has **16G** of memory available.
I have tried setting the Java stack parameters
`-Xms1g and -Xmx8g`
at the command line when I invoke Java, and also using the `"export _JAVA_OPTS" to no avail`.

> Java says it is "picking up" the Xms and Xmx values and when I run 
>   Java -XshowSettings:vm it shows that I have a max heap size of approx. 7.9G.

But Alloy doesn't let me increase the memory beyond the tiny minimum size of 768M. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers are hardcoded in Alloy although 4.2 should have 4Gb included? (There are a number of variants of 4.2 out there I think.)

We're working on creating a 5.0.0 version at the moment but that is not really publishable yet. You can download a snapshot JAR from:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/alloytools/org.alloytools.alloy.dist/5.0.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: I will give try your 5.0.0 version. I also tried running the 4.2 release on Windows 10. With 32b Java, I can't set memory larger than ~3GB. I really need 4GB or more for my application. With 64b Java, I get 4GB of memory, but MiniSAT is not available according to Alloy warning message ("JNI-based SAT solver does not work on this platform) so my only option is SAT4J. Unfortunately that solver runs out of memory. My co-worker is running Alloy with Java natively on Mac OS. When he runs with 4GB of memory using MiniSAT, it runs to completion. Alloy with MiniSAT for 64b Windows is needed. Thanks!

Comment: Which of the .jar files should I use? I am running on Windows 64b at this point. I get "main manifest" error when I try to run the *sources.jar file or the *javadoc.jar file. When I run org.alloytools.alloy.dist-5.0.0-20170823.080526-1.jar I get a JNI error, exception in thread main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apple/eawt/ApplicationListener.

Comment: This is the latest snapshot today (2017/10/31) https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/alloytools/org.alloytools.alloy.dist/5.0.0-SNAPSHOT/org.alloytools.alloy.dist-5.0.0-20170823.135410-3.jar

Comment: The problem with Windows is that it does not support libraries that minisat is using and some of the other native solvers are using. This is a pity because the missing functions are just about timing :-(

Comment: Thanks - bummer about Windows. I tried the latest snapshot you pointed me to on my Ubuntu Linux VM running OpenJDK 64b 1.8.0_131 and get this error:  Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apple/eawt/ApplicationListener
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)

Comment: I think this is fixed now, you can download the latest release from https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/alloytools/org.alloytools.alloy.dist/5.0.0-SNAPSHOT Make sure you pick the latest version of the jar.

Comment: BTW, please report issues for this on the repo https://github.com/AlloyTools/org.alloytools.alloy/issues

Comment: Peter, I tried the latest jar file, from 11/3/17, and now I can set my memory to a much larger value, up to 16G. This is running on my Ubuntu 64b Linux VM, using 64b JRE. (I didn't try Windows since it doesn't give me the solver I want.) I am re-executing my .als test cases to see if they run to completion now. Incidentally, we are using Alloy to look for deadlocks in a computer system composed of black-box elements that define in-out dependencies among the various virtual channels. Thanks for your help!